# How do I get the registerID and log a user into a Webex meeting?

Tags: webex

Per the documentation for the CreateMeetingAttendee command:

If  is enabled in the CreateTrainingSession or
CreateMeeting request, then CreateMeetingAttendee returns a unique registerID for each
attendee. This registerID value can be specified when each attendee joins the session using the
Training Center URL API m.php?AT=JM&MK=meetingKey...&RID=registerID command.

However, when running this command the only value I get back is an attendeeID.  So I tried to use that instead per the documentation after starting the meeting on another computer, and pointed this computer to:

https://ourUrl.webex.com/ourUrl/m.php?AT=JM&MK=737613582&RID=5220431022

The MK value is listed on the meeting details page and was the same one used successfully in the CreateMeetingAttendee command.  The RID is the attendeeID that was returned from CreateMeetingAttendee (I also tried RegisterMeetingAttendee, as the documentation gives no information to differentiate the two or explain which should be used).  In both cases I was taken to a Webex page that says "Enter the meeting number to join."  This indicates to me that the MK and/or RID was not accepted as valid and so I was just sent to a home screen.  I tried without the RID with similar results.

What is going wrong in this process, and what is the correct way to use the API to get a user logged in so that after clicking a button on our site s/he is sent directly into the meeting?

Answer (score 1):

Through trial and error I have found a process that works.  After using RegisterMeetingAttendee, the user shows up in the registration list.  I don't store any value returned from this call, and instead make a post to the meeting page using the following parameters, identifying the attendee by email address:

```
 <form action="https://pmimeetings-test.webex.com/pmimeetings-test/m.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="AT" value="JM">
    <input type="hidden" name="MK" value="[meeting key]">
    <input type="hidden" name="AN" value="Test User 1">
    <input type="hidden" name="AE" value="[user's email]">
    <input type="hidden" name="PW" value="test">
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

This redirects the attendee to the page where they can download the Webex meeting initiator.

I will try to wait to hear back from Webex, if they ever respond, before marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing that this answer comes late in the game, I'd recommend using the XML API to register attendees and pull the join URL. All XML API documentation is available at webexdeveloper.com -> Develop and Test -> XML API -> XML API Reference. The specific API calls you'll want to check out are RegisterMeetingAttendee and GetjoinurlMeeting.

When calling GetjoinurlMeeting, you'll want to make sure you supply all of the values that the meeting was scheduled with. For example, if you required registration, you will need to provide the attendee's registration ID. If the meeting requires a password to join, you'll need to supply that as well.

Assuming you supply all required values, GetjoinurlMeeting will generate a URL that will join an attendee into the meeting in one fell swoop, otherwise it will drop them on the join page that requires user intervention to continue the join process (enter name, email, registrationID, etc.)